# How to iterate through the array completely?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have following code where I am trying to print out the booksAssigned and booksAssignedDue depending on ChaptersToRead

```
var books:[String] = ["Hobbit","LOTR","Fellowship"]
var chaptersToRead:[[Int]] = [[1],[1,2],[2]]

var booksAssigned:[String] = []
var booksAssignedDue:[String] = []

for (index, chapters) in chaptersToRead.enumerated() {
    if chapters.contains(1) {
        booksAssigned.append(books[index])
    }
    else
    {
        booksAssignedDue.append(books[index])
    }
}
```

My expected output is this

```
print(booksAssigned) = ["Hobbit","LOTR"]
print(booksAssignedDue) = ["LOTR","Fellowship"]
```

but I am getting this

```
print(booksAssigned) = ["Hobbit","LOTR"]
print(booksAssignedDue) = ["Fellowship"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (index, chapters) in chaptersToRead.enumerated() {
    if chapters.contains(1) {
        booksAssigned.append(books[index])
    }
    //You should not use `else` here.
    if chapters.contains(2) {
        booksAssignedDue.append(books[index])
    }
}
```

If you use `else` at the place at marked, the book added to `booksAssigned` cannot be added to `booksAssignedDue`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Pair-wise relations between two sequences: consider using `zip(_:_:)`

When you are working with sequences (/ordered collections) that have pair-wise element relations (such as the book in `books` and the associated chapter list in `chaptersToRead`), it is appropriate and useful to work with a zipped sequence, using the global [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) function:

```
// no need to explicitly annotate type: it will be correctly inferred
let books =          ["Hobbit", "LOTR", "Fellowship"]
let chaptersToRead = [[1],      [1,2],  [2]]

// apply a flatMap over the zipped collection of the books and the
// associated chapters to read, with a 'nil' conditional for the '1'
// and '2' inclusions for booksAssigned and booksAssignedDue, respectively.
let booksAssigned = zip(books, chaptersToRead)
    .flatMap { $1.contains(1) ? $0 : nil }
let booksAssignedDue = zip(books, chaptersToRead)
    .flatMap { $1.contains(2) ? $0 : nil }

print(booksAssigned)    // ["Hobbit", "LOTR"]
print(booksAssignedDue) // ["LOTR", "Fellowship"]
```

With this approach, you needn't pre-declare and repeatedly append to a mutable array, but can directly instantiate the `booksAssigned` arrays using the `flatMap` operation on the zipped sequence. You can also avoid explicitly accessing the index of an array using an index that is received from an external "source" (in this case, indices of another, although related, array), an approach that can lead to dangers as the index to be used is not validated prior to use.

Also note that I've changed all the arrays above to immutables: it is good practice to use immutables unless you are certain you will mutate the property/variable (possibly you want mutables in the real context in which you apply this implementation).

---

#### Make use of an appropriate data structure

Another insight when working with closely related sequences is that you might want to consider simply joining these pair-wise element in an appropriate type (e.g. that covers both the boks title and the chapters to read associated with the book) which will allow simply using a single array with elements of this type, rather than several separate arrays.

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let chaptersToRead: [Int]
}
/* possibly `chaptersToRead` should be a mutable property rather 
   than an immutable one, in case you plan to mutate it for an 
   existing `Book` instance.                                      */

let books = [Book(title: "Hobbit",     chaptersToRead: [1]),
             Book(title: "LOTR",       chaptersToRead: [1, 2]),
             Book(title: "Fellowship", chaptersToRead: [2])]

let booksAssigned = books
    .flatMap { $0.chaptersToRead.contains(1) ? $0.title : nil }
let booksAssignedDue = books
    .flatMap { $0.chaptersToRead.contains(2) ? $0.title : nil }

print(booksAssigned)    // ["Hobbit", "LOTR"]
print(booksAssignedDue) // ["LOTR", "Fellowship"]
```

Or, using this approach, you might want to work with filtered `Book` instances rather than just their `title` properties:

```
let booksAssigned = books.filter { $0.chaptersToRead.contains(1) }
let booksAssignedDue = books.filter { $0.chaptersToRead.contains(2) }
```

If you are set on getting the titles associated with a given array of `Book` instances as an array of `String` instances, these are readily obtainable applying `.map { $0.title }` on the `[Book]` arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations about pair-wise relationships and ways to design appropriate data structures. I will start incorporating them.

Comment: @Coder221 happy to help.